# Implementation of TypeORM in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, express, typeorm

I was looking among ORMs available to express server and I found TypeORM,my question here is what is the best way to implement/organize a small project using it, actually I found a repo in official documentation, here is the link:

https://github.com/typeorm/typescript-express-example}

But I feel awkward wrapping all server in database connection so I haven't found an implementation yet, even I don't know if the documentation example is the best one, however I tried to create my own implementation, and it looks like this:

**dbconnection.ts**

```
import { getConnectionManager } from "typeorm";
export const db = (async() =>{
    const connectionManager = getConnectionManager();
    const connection = connectionManager.create({
        type: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 5432,
        username: "sample",
        password: "sample",
        database: "sample",
    });
    await connection.connect()
    .then(()=> console.log("DB connected"))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

**server.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { db } from "./settings/dbconnection";
const server: express.Application = express();
db();
server.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
server.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});
server.listen(server.get('port'), function() {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${server.get('port')}`);
});
```

Thanks in advance, hope this will be useful for other devs in the future. :)

Comment: Are you open to alternatives to Type ORM, because it is not well documented and well supported.

Comment: Sure, what do you recommend?, Also I want a ORM that has a great integration with TypeScript, for that reason I chose TypeORM at the beginning

Comment: You can try Sequelize ORM , https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Comment: I will check it out, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the next implementation, hope it helps

**dbConnection.ts**

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
const dbConnection = async() => {
      await createConnection({
            type: 'postgres',
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: Number(process.env.PORT),
            username: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASS,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            entities: [__dirname + '/models/*.js']
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Database connected'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export default dbConnection;
```

**server.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import "reflect-metadata";
import dbConnection from './dbConnection';
const server = express();
server.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
server.listen(server.get('port'), async() => {
    console.log(`Server listenning on port ${server.get('port')}`);
    await dbConnection();
});
```

With this, you will be able to use dbConnection inside server object.